# How to add data to object when keys retrieve only 1 object? PARSE.COM SWIFT

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, parse-platform

Okay I have a classNamed: "PrivateGroups". Each row in PrivateGroups contains "GroupName" and "Password". In a UIView, if the user enters the GroupName and Password and hits submit, I want to add their user objectId to that specific groupname/password entry under "members".

This is the code I have that isn't working:

```
var query = PFQuery(className: "PrivateGroups")

query.whereKey("privatename", equalTo: joinname.text)

query.whereKey("password", equalTo: joinpassword.text)

query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in

if objects.count == 1 {

for object in objects {

query.getFirstObject().addUniqueObject(PFUser.currentUser().objectId, forKey: "members")

query.getFirstObject().saveInBackground() }}
```

[image: This is what the className looks like]

so if you match the "members" and "password" and press the button, i want to add the user's object id to "members"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your loop `for object in objects` you shouldn't need to also call `query.getFirstObject()` since you already have the object. Instead, try

```
for object in objects {
       if let arr = object["members"]{
          if(arr.containsObject(PFUser.currentUser().objectID == false){
             arr.addObject(PFUser.currentUser().objectID)
             object.saveInBackground()
          }
       }   
}
```

Comment: oh my bad, that isn't the issue in my project i use query1, throughout. i edited the post to reflect that. any clue?

Comment: I thought that my just be a typo! Just to make sure, your "members" column is declared as an array in Parse, right? Also, are you getting an error message when running the code?

Comment: Get a error, Cannot invoke 'add unique object' with and argument list type (String!)

Comment: Sorry, forgot `addUniqueObject` takes more than just one input. Changed that in my answer.